# Paginate Many to Many

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have a many to many relationship that looks like so

batches -> batch_contributors -> contributors

I am running into an issue when attempting to paginate, I am doing the following:

```
$contributions = Batch::with('contributors')->where('id', '=' , $batchid)->paginate(10);
```

Here are samples from my parsed JSON (faker data)

[parsed JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vg9L.png)

[end of parsed JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mV1H.png)

My problem is the contributor records are listed under the single batch record, so pagination is seeing this and loading all 100 contributors on the first page instead of 10 per page.

How do I get pagination to look at the contributor level instead of the batch level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just invert the call and get contributors where batchId is equal to the one u parse, something like this:

```
Contributor::with(['batches' => function($query) use ($batchId) {
    $query->where('id', $batchId);
}])->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes, which makes pagination work correctly but now it is pulling in contributors who are not in the batch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Batch::with('contributors', function($query){
    $query->take(10); // to take 10 contributors for all the 10 selected Batchs
})->where('id', '=' , $batchid)->paginate(10);
```

Laravel will get 10 contributors in this case, and try to map them into the batchs, So If those 10 contributors belong to one batch, the rest batchs won't have any contributors.